# Impeachment and Removal from Office

Tags: united-states, impeachment

Is there any recourse should Congress protect President from impeachment and removal from office despite solid grounds for such actions?

Comment: Are you asking "Is there a way to impeach a President if Congress doesn't want to?"  As written, this isn't very clear.

Comment: I assume you mean legally, as opposed to [Trump's implied strategy for preventing Hillary Clinton from exercising power](https://www.bostonglobe.com/news/politics/2016/08/09/trump-implies-second-amendment-people-could-something-about-clinton/GCOhuvpq4VNyR0VI34uZON/story.html) if the election failed to stop her from reaching that point.

Answer (score 14):

US voters have an opportunity to replace their House Representative every 24 months.

If enough people in a district don't like what their representative is or isn't doing, they can elect a new one.

This pressure from the people is what turned the House Reps against Nixon in 1974. Only when it became clear that the people would not support a Congress that supported Nixon did the impeachment process begin.

Comment: FYI, the House and Senate both had a Democratic majority throughout Nixon's second term.